# Dismissing the keyboard after tableviewcontroller selection

Tags: ios, keyboard, uipopovercontroller

I have this scenario:

The user searches for a client in a UISearchBar - the results are displayed in a popover controller and the search is an autopopulating one like google - type in D and you get all results with a D, add an 'r' so it's Dr and your results filter to only those with Dr in it. The popovercontroller's viewcontroller is a tableviewcontroller. User selects a result from the table, that popovercontroller closes and opens a second one, also with a tableviewcontroller that has items associated with the client they selected. At this point the keyboard is still displayed, which is fine. However, when they select a row in this tableview the keyboard should close.

I've tried placing [self setEditing:NO animated:YES] in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of both tableviewcontrollers as well as in popoverControllerDidDismissPopover method in my root viewcontroller but the keyboard doesn't dismiss.

Also tried this:

- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
  return NO;
  }

with no luck.

Am I not understanding who owns the keyboard here?

Comment: The UISearchBar I suppose holds the keyboard here...You can try [yoursearchbar resignFirstResponsder];. I did this a while ago & it had worked. I didn't post this as an answer as I'm unsure if I had used a popOver & table view controller.

Comment: It's `[yoursearchbar resignFirstResponder]` and I believe that is correct. To dismiss the keyboard, you `resignFirstResponder` on the item that called the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate for the UISearchBar: UISearchBarDelegate and add the appropriate method.

In the interface builder click the search bar and drag the delegate from the connectivity tab to the current view Controller; then add  to the implementation of that view controller and call this delegate method.

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar*)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

OR create a UISearchBar property and resign that property inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    .... // Your code
    .... // Your code
}
```